# How jena SPARQL results in RDF XML format rather than triple

Tags: sparql, jena, triples, rdf-xml

I wrote SPARQL in String queryString

```
 "SELECT DISTINCT ?dog ?p ?o " +
            "WHERE {" +
            "?dog <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://test#dog>. " +
            "?dog ?p ?o. " +
            "}";
```

...

```
   while (rs_s.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution qs = rs_s.next();
        String s1 = qs.get("dog").toString();
        String s2 = qs.get("p").toString();
        String s3 = qs.get("o").toString();
```

As a result, I got a triple format.
How do I get it with RDF XML?

Comment: wrong query type, use a `CONSTRUCT` query, see [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) - and Jena will return a `Model` then which you can serialize as RDF/XML

Comment: Are you saying that if I use CONSTRUCT query, I can make RDF XML with Model.write?

Comment: well, yes - the whole idea of `CONSTRUCT` queries is to return proper RDF data, and in Jena you'll get the result as a `Model` object which you can write to disk in "RDF/XML" syntax

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does the word "wrong query type" mean?
"CONSTRUCT DISTINCT ?dog ?p ?o " +
"WHERE {" +
"?dog <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://test#dog>. " +
"?dog ?p ?o. " +
"}";
Does this mean that RDF data comes out?
What is output?

Comment: (1) Syntax, `CONSTRUCT {..} WHERE {..}` (2) call `QueryExecution.execConstruct` to get a Model.

Comment: I can't call QueryExecution.execConstruct. 
Where is the library located?
I did : import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
So, I can use QueryExecution and result came out as a triple